# What's an inclusive way of asking for a user's gender and sexual orientation?

Tags: users, gender, inclusive-design, user-profile

I need to ask for users' genders and sexual orientations in a normalized way that allows for filtering users on both properties (so I can't just store user-provider strings). What's the most inclusive way to do this?

For genders, [ISO_5218](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:5218:ed-1:v2:en) recommends having the options: 0 (not known), 1 (male), 2 (female) and 9 (not applicable); but this groups a lot of people who identify in many distinct ways in the same bucket. For sexual orientations I haven't found a standard.

Right now I'm thinking of having a set of genders and a set of sexual orientations that users can pick from, as well as having the option to provide a custom string for both. But that's not great for filtering (custom strings would not fall into any filters), and I don't know what genders and sexual orientations to include in the list.

Are there any inclusive established practices for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Williams Institute of the UCLA Law School published a paper titled [Best Practices for Asking Questions to Identify Transgender and Other Gender Minority Respondents on Population-Based Surveys](http://williamsinstitute.law.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/geniuss-report-sep-2014.pdf). It's a culmination of studies by the Gender Identity in U.S. Surveillance (GenIUSS) group about the best way to accurately identify transgender people and other gender minorities in surveys.

**They recommend that when two questions can be included they be asked as:**

> ASSIGNED SEX AT BIRTH
>
> What sex were you assigned at birth, on your original birth certificate?
>
> - Male
> - Female
>
> CURRENT GENDER IDENTITY
>
> How do you describe yourself? (check one)
>
> - Male
> - Female
> - Transgender
> - Do not identify as female, male, or transgender

(They're also exploring a further breakdown of the responses for the Current Gender Identity question using the options "male," "female," "trans male/trans man," "trans female/trans woman," "genderqueer/gender non-conforming," and "different identity (please state): _______")

**When only a single question can be included in a response form, the report recommends phrasing it as**

> Some people describe themselves as transgender when they experience a different gender identity from their sex at birth. For example, a
>   person born into a male body, but who feels female or lives as a
>   woman. Do you consider yourself to be transgender?
>
> - Yes, transgender, male to female
> - Yes, transgender, female to male
> - Yes, transgender, gender non-conforming
> - No

**The paper also includes a recommended way of asking about LGBT identity:**

> Do you think of yourself as (please check all that apply):
>
> - Straight
> - Gay or lesbian
> - Bisexual
> - Transgender, transsexual, or gender non-conforming
>
> IF yes to transgender, then probe:
>
> - transgender or transsexual, male to female
> - transgender or transsexual, female to male
> - Gender non-conforming

The paper also provides some recommendations on collecting this data from adolescents, ethnic minorities, and low socio-economic status communities.

Comment: Thanks! This is specifically for a conversational UI, so the user will reply to the question by typing something. Should I try to match their answer to one of these bullets and reply with a "did you mean...?"-type question?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the solution you suggested is the right one, allowing a string input if the options provided aren't satisfactory. A category of "Other" could be used to stand for these inputs. (Even without the custom input field, you would need an "Other" option to be all-inclusive.)

Edit: If "Other" sounds harsh, perhaps "Acategorical" might work better.